# What are the possible ways to achieve mixBlendMode effects in React?

Tags: reactjs, mix-blend-mode

In my code I want to set various `mixBlendMode` values through styles for specific images.
But React seems to not interprete the `mixBlendMode` parameter. So what are the options?

```
...

return ({backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
         color: 'white',
         mixBlendMode: 'difference'});
```

Here is the whole App code if one needs:

```
import React from 'react';
import SwiperImagesStack from './media/swiper-images/SwiperImagesIndex';
import SwiperTexts from './SlideTexts';
import './css/MainSwiper.css';
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y, EffectFade } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';


export default function MainSwiper() {
  const CaseFotos = [19, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 18, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 3, 5];
  
   const mybg = (m, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      if ([10, 13].includes(m) === true) {
        return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                  alignItems: 'flex-end' });
        }
      else if ([1, 4, 6, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18].includes(m) === true) {
        return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  alignItems: 'flex-end' });
        }
      else if ( m === 16) {
        return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end', 
                  alignItems: 'flex-start' });
      }
      else {
        return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')` });
      }
    }
    else {
      return ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][m]}')`,
    color: 'white',
    mixBlendMode: 'difference' });
    }
  }


  return (
  
    <Swiper
      modules={[Navigation, EffectFade]}
      navigation
      speed={900}
      slidesPerView={1}
      loop
      className="MainSwiper">
        {CaseFotos.map((n, index) => 
          <SwiperSlide className='SwiperSlide'  id={`case${index}`} style={mybg(Math.floor(Math.random() * (n-1)), index)} >
            <div className='categoryWrapper'>
              <h2 className="case-text">
                <strong> {`${SwiperTexts[index]}`} </strong>
                  <button>
                    <span>
                      <span>
                        <span data-attr-span="See how">
                          See how
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                  </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>)
        }
    </Swiper> 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works! I had to set styles for different divs upon the randomly selected picture for each slide, so here is how I've done it below. It seems to be quite rude for a React writer, so if one knows how to improve the code below, please suggest!

```
import React from 'react';
import SwiperImagesStack from './media/swiper-images/SwiperImagesIndex';
import SwiperTexts from './SlideTexts';
import './css/MainSwiper.css';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide} from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/effect-fade';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';
import 'swiper/css/lazy';

import { Navigation, Pagination, EffectFade, Autoplay, A11y, Lazy } from 'swiper';

export default function MainSwiper() {
  
const fArray = [19, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 17, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 3, 5];  
const randomedFArray = fArray.map(n => Math.round(Math.random() * (n-1)));

function SlideStyle(index) {
    
  function JusCon (index, n) {
    if (index === 0 && [10, 13, 16].includes(n)) 
      {return 'flex-end'}
    else 
      {return 'flex-start'};
  }
  
  function AliIte (index, n) {
    if (index === 0 && [1, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18].includes(n)) 
      {return 'flex-end'}
    else 
      {return 'flex-start'};
  }
  
  function TexCol (index, n) {
    if (index === 0 && [0, 8, 9, 10, 14, 17].includes(n)) 
      {return 'black'}
    else 
      {return 'white'};
  }
  
  function MixMod (index, n) {
    if (index === 0 && [10, 14, 17].includes(n)) 
      {return 'overlay'}
    else if (index === 0 && [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].includes(n)) 
      {return 'normal'}
    else 
      {return 'color-dodge'};
  }
  
  return ([ { backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][randomedFArray[index]]}')`,
              justifyContent: JusCon(index,randomedFArray[index]),
              alignItems: AliIte(index,randomedFArray[index]) },

            { color: TexCol(index,randomedFArray[index]),
              mixBlendMode: MixMod(index,randomedFArray[index]) }
      ]);
}

return (
    
    <Swiper
        spaceBetween={1}
        slidesPerView={1}
        navigation={true}
        effect={"fade"}
        lazy={true}
        speed={400}
        autoplay={{delay: 5500}}
        pagination={{
        clickable: true,
        }}
        loop={true}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, A11y, EffectFade, Lazy]}
        className="MainSwiper"
      >
          
        {(Array.from(Array(fArray.length).keys())).map((index) => 
          <SwiperSlide className="SwiperSlide swiper-lazy" key={`slide${index}`} id={`case${index}`} style={SlideStyle(index)[0]}  >
            <div className='categoryWrapper swiper-lazy'>
              <h2 className="case-text" style={SlideStyle(index)[1]}>
                <strong> {`${SwiperTexts[index]}`} </strong>
                  <button>
                    <span>
                      <span>
                        <span data-attr-span="See how">
                          See how
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                  </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div className="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
          </SwiperSlide>)
        }
    </Swiper> 
  );
}
```